# Referencing Video Stored in NSDocumentDirectory from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, html, video

I'm building a hybrid web app and native iOS app and looking to show videos that have been recorded on the local device and stored in NSDocumentDirectory to be shown in a UIWebView.

Currently this does not seem to be working based on the below code - the file exists but I think the referencing to the file from the HTML may be incorrect.

```
NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *videoPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",fileName]];

BOOL fileExist =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:videoPath];    
if(fileExist) {
    NSLog(@"File Exist in path");
} else {
    NSLog(@"NO File Exist");
}

videoPath = [videoPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
videoPath = [videoPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<video width=\"320\" height=\"240\" controls><source src=\"%@\" type=\"video/mp4\"></video>", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@/",videoPath]];
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('videoList').innerHTML = '%@'", htmlString];
NSString *result = [self.livingWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);

The output of the JavaScript injection is:

Result: <video width="320" height="240" controls><source src="file:////var//mobile//Applications//76FE06FB-39D3-4658-8B52-AFE9DBE0C524//Documents//23-07-2013-16-54-48.mp4/" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];` to convert the path into a file:// URL.  Then put that into your htmlString.  Don't do the manual stuff you're doing with stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString, you're missing some conversions.